# Help translating a sentence - Playing cards

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление, лексикон

Disclaimer: I'm a true beginner with the Russian language.

I struggle translating a riddle:

> I'm between the King and the Queen - where am I?

The ‘King’ and the ‘Queen’ being playing card, it seems that ‘Queen’ would be translated `дама` in this context, but should ‘King’ stay `король` ?

Also, what's most correct:

> Я между королем и дамой - Где я ?

vs

> Я между король и дама - Где я ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In playing cards, ‘Queen’ is *дама* and ‘King’ is *король*. The first variant of the translation is absolutely correct,

> Я между королем и дамой - Где я ?

Also, `королем` can be spelled as `королём` which is even more correct. Whenever a Russian word has the letter `ё`, one is free to spell it as `e`, still the pronunciation remains that of `ё`, that is, [jo] or [o] with the previous consonant palatalized, the latter being the case with `королём`/`королем` [kərɐˈlʲom].

In the second variant of translation the cases are wrong, both nouns after *между* must be in the Instrumental case, not in the Nominative.

Comment: @Heagon - Really? Who on earth uses Genitive after _между_? Who will say _*между дома и сарая_ or _*между меня и тебя_? If such usage really still exists somewhere, it is definitely **not recommended** for beginner level learners, it is **not worth noting**.

Comment: @Heagon There is one more clarification. The nouns after *между* can  be in genitive case only for *между nessery  X* or   *между nessery  X and nessery  Y*. It can't  be in genitive case for *между one  X and   one Y*. Между двух столбов. Между двумя столбами. Между столбом и стеной. But we can't say: "*Между столба и стены. Между дамы и короля*"

Comment: @Heagon - I've edited the question to exclude mentioning the Genitive case which is marked as “obsolete” already in the 1930s Ushakov's dictionary.